# How can I start a new zsh instance that sources a particular file?

Tags: zsh, environment-variables

I have a script at `/venv/bin/activate` that sets some environment variables. I’m looking for a way to start zsh, have it source this script, and then continue with a normal interactive session. When I exit this session, the session I return to should not know about any of the environment changes that `activate` made. How can I invoke zsh like this?

(This is pretty much the same question as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294684/88560), except that I’m using zsh instead of bash.)

Comment: Similar: [Start zsh with a custom zshrc](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/131716). [My answer there](/a/131735) will give you some approaches.

Comment: Since asking this question I’ve started using [direnv](https://direnv.net/), which is a tool that integrates with zsh, bash, and others to set “per-directory environment variables” in a way that is very close to what I was asking for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `activate` script only sets environment variables, you can read it in one shell, then execute a new, interactive zsh instance.

```
sh -c '. /venv/bin/activate; exec zsh -i'
```

The wrapper shell `sh` can be replaced by any shell that is able to parse `/venv/bin/activate`, including `zsh` if the `activate` script is compatible with it.

In addition to environment variables, the interactive zsh instance will inherit the process ID and a few other process settings such as resource limits (`ulimit …`) and ignored signals (`trap '' …`). On the other hand, settings of the shell itself are not preserved: shell variables (`var=…` if `var` is not exported), shell options (`set -…` or `shopt …`), key bindings, alias and function definitions, etc.

Obviously this won't work if your `.zshrc` overrides environment variables set by the `activate` script. That's one of the reasons [`.*shrc` files should not set environment variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107851/using-export-in-bashrc/197333#197333).

Comment: This is a good solution as long as you don’t need to return to the original shell afterward (and as long as the effects of `activate` fall into only the categories you mentioned).

Comment: @bdesham Yes, I meant that you should run that as a separate shell script but I can see that it isn't clear, I'll clarify.

Comment: Oh, even better. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: This doesn't work with modern zsh (nb it works if the final shell command is `sh` or `bash`, for example)

Comment: @jmetz What doesn't work? It certainly works with Python virtual environments, and I don't see what recent changes in zsh could break similar scripts from other communities. The only thing I can see that would break it is if you do something weird in your `.zshrc` like overriding `PATH`. In which case, don't do this.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - overriding `PATH` is indeed the culprit then it seems... though I'd have though that this is fairly standard practice meaning your answer is only useful in limited scenarios. Or have I been overriding `PATH` in the wrong place..?

Comment: Regardless, I'd suggest adding an emphasized note to your answer highlighting the `PATH` issue, as I doubt I'd be the only person left scratching my head after trying your answer.

Comment: @jmetz No, [setting environment variables in `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` is bad practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107851/using-export-in-bashrc/197333#197333), in part because it breaks per-session environments as you noticed.

Comment: @jmetz I don't really see what to add to my answer. Your problem has nothing to do with this question: it's independent of the shell, whereas the question is about using a sh script with zsh.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Have you tried googling "setting PATH zsh"? Pretty much every result suggests setting `PATH` in `.zshrc`, so bad practice or no, your answer needs to take the fact that there are probably many `zshrc`s with `PATH` setting in them.

Comment: @jmetz In my experience this bad recommendation almost always mentions `.bashrc` and is partly due to the bizarre treatment of shrc files by bash. But ok, I've added a warning not to do this. Maybe the bad practice has migrated to zsh with macOS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120831/discussion-between-jmetz-and-gilles-so-stop-being-evil).

Answer (score 1):

### Using `ZDOTDIR`

Create a (possibly temporary) directory at, say, `~/venv_startup` that contains two files, .zshenv and .zshrc. The .zshenv file consists of

```sh
source ~/.zshenv
source /venv/bin/activate
```

while .zshrc says

```sh
source ~/.zshrc
```

Now, invoke zsh via

```sh
zsh -c "ZDOTDIR=~/venv_startup zsh"
```

This says to zsh, “instead of starting out by sourcing the .zshenv and .zshrc files in `$HOME`, source the files of those names in `/venv_startup` instead.” Since the versions in `/venv_startup` source the ones in `$HOME` anyway, the net effect is that the shell will run

```sh
source /venv/bin/activate
```

in between executing your zshenv and your zshrc. After that, it will be a normal interactive session.